Uncertainty propagation for quadratic interpolation
I have timeseries data $(t_i, y_i)$ with uncertainties $\Delta y$. I need to interpolate this data to match the timestamps with the timestamps of another dataset.
Theory
To propagate the uncertainties, I did find a reference. The important part is Section 2:
The uncertainty of an interpolated value $\Delta \hat y$ for some interpolation function $\hat y = S(t, a_1,\dots,a_N)$ which was fitted to $\left[(t_1, y_1),\dots,(t_N, y_N)\right]$ can be calculated with
$$
\Delta \hat y^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial t_i} \right)^2 \Delta t_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} \right)^2 \Delta y_i^2 .
$$
So far, so standard. Now the interesting part: One can calculate
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial t_i} = \left. -\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} \right|_{t=t_i} \sum_{j=1}^N M^{-1}_{ij}\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} = \sum_{j=1}^N M^{-1}_{ij}\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}
$$
with
$$
M_{ij} = \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial a_i} \right|_{t=t_j}
$$
Let's apply it!
I only have uncertainties in $y$ (as the timestamps are assumed to be correct). My interpolation function is a polynomial of second order:
$$
S(t, a_1, a_2, a_3) = a_1 + a_2t + a_3t^2
$$
This results in
$$
\Delta \hat y^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} \right)^2 \Delta y_i^2
$$
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} = \sum_{j=1}^N M^{-1}_{ij}\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}
$$
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
t_1^2 & t_2^2 & t_3^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
t \\
t^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Code
I wrote a small script to checkout the algorithm.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

@np.vectorize(excluded=[1, 2])
def calc_err(t_new, t, yerr):
    M = np.array([np.ones_like(t), t, t**2])
    M_inv = np.invert(M)
    S_a = np.array([1, t_new, t_new**2])

    return np.sqrt((((M_inv @ S_a) * yerr) ** 2).sum())


def plot(t, y, delta_y):
    t_hat = np.linspace(t[0], t[-1])
    f = make_interp_spline(t, y, k=2)
    y_hat = f(t_hat)

    delta_y_hat = calc_err(t_hat, t, delta_y)

    plt.title("Uncertainty propagation for linear interpolation")
    plt.errorbar(t, y, yerr=delta_y, fmt=".", c="black", barsabove=True, capsize=10, label="$y$")
    plt.plot(t_hat, y_hat, c="gray", label="$\hat y$")
    plt.plot(t_hat, y_hat + delta_y_hat, "--", c="red", label="$\Delta \hat y$")
    plt.plot(t_hat, y_hat - delta_y_hat, "--", c="red")
    plt.legend()


plot(np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([3.1, 4.1, 1.6]), np.array([0.7, 0.4, 0.6]))

But sadly, the resulting uncertainty does not look right and is way to big (I assume at $t_i$ the uncertainty should be $\Delta y_i$). What have I done wrong?


I don't know what's wrong in the above code or theory. But I did find a much simpler way to propagate uncertainty for a bunch of different interpolation scheme in this paper

The interpolation is a linear combination of the data,
$$\hat{y}(t) = \sum_i \omega_i(t)\,y_i,$$
whence (for uncorrelated errors) the variance of the interpolated value at any point is the weighted sum with the squared weights
$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat{y}(t)) = \sum_i\omega_i(t)^2\operatorname{Var}(y_i).\tag{*}$$
If we take "$\Delta y_i$" to mean some fixed multiple of the standard deviation,
$$\Delta y_i = Z\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(y_i)},$$
then the solution is similarly to multiply the square root of $(*)$ by that multiple $Z.$  The factor of $Z$ rides through the calculation from beginning to end, yielding

$$\Delta(\hat{y}(t)) = \sqrt{\sum_i\omega_i(t)^2\Delta y_i}.$$


Here is a plot for the data $t = (1,2,3),$ $y = (1,2,3),$ and $\Delta y_i = ((3.1,4.1,1.6) - (.7,.4,.6))/2$ as suggested by the code in the question:

NB: This solution assumes all error is independent measurement error, as suggested by how the question is formulated.  More sophisticated models, such as Gaussian Processes (interpolated using some form of Kriging) can be formulated and exploited to account for prediction error under weaker assumptions about the interpolation function -- but their correct identification and application is an art in itself, not adequately treatable in any single post.

To illustrate the details, the following code in R is implemented to be highly general (not efficient!).  It implements any interpolator linear in the y-values: simply change the weight function to supply the interpolator's weight $\omega_i(t)$ (which depends only on $t$ and the abscissas $(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$) for the ith y-value at a specified abscissa $t$ = t.0 and the rest will work.  I demonstrate this by offering two weighting functions.  The previous illustration is polynomial interpolation; the IDW(2) interpolator is shown below.
#
# Function to return weight[i] at t.0 for abscissas t.
# -- Lagrangian polynomial interpolation --
#
weight <- Vectorize(function(i, t.0, t) {
  prod((t.0 - t[-i]) / (t[i] - t[-i]))
}, "i")
#
# Function to return weight[i] at t.0 for abscissas t.
# -- IDW(p) --
#
weight <- Vectorize(function(i, t.0, t, p = 2, tol = 1e-8 * diff(range(t))) {
  d <- abs(t.0 - t)
  r <- max(d) / min(d)
  if (!is.finite(r)) {
    if (d[i] <= tol) return(1.0) else return(0.0)
  }
  d <- d^(-p)
  d[i] / sum(d)
}, "i")
#
# Function to interpolate (t, y) data at t.0.
# Returns a named (column) vector including the interpolated value `y.hat` and
# the interpolated delta `delta`.
#
interpolate <- Vectorize(function(t.0, y, dy, t) {
  w <- weight(seq_along(t), t.0, t)
  c(t = t.0,                      # Interpolation point
    y = sum(w * y),               # Interpolated value
    delta = sqrt(sum(w^2 * dy^2)),# Interpolated "delta"
    weight = w)                   # The weight vector
}, "t.0")
#
# Specify the (t, y, dy) data.
#
df <- data.frame(t = 1:3,
                 y = c(1, 2, 3),
                 delta = (c(3.1, 4.1, 1.6) - c(0.7, 0.4, 0.6)) / 2)
#
# Interpolate y and dy along the range of t.
#
n <- 101
x <- seq(min(df$t), max(df$t), length.out = n)
df.interpolated <- as.data.frame(with(df, t(interpolate(x, y, delta, t))))
#
# Plot the interpolation and the data.
#
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.interpolated, aes(t, y, ymin = y - delta, ymax = y + delta)) + 
  geom_ribbon(fill = gray(0.8), color = "Red", linewidth = 1.2) + 
  geom_path(linewidth = 1.2) + 
  geom_errorbar(data = df, width = 0.0, linetype = 3, linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point(data = df, size = 2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = t) + 
  ggtitle("Data with Error Bars, Interpolation, and Interpolated Errors")



Thank you very much for this great answer!
This is explaining what is also shown in the paper I linked in my comment to this question.
I still don't know what I did wrong in my implementation, as (if I understood correctly) this should also calculate the uncertainties (in a arguably more complicated way).
But I will simply go with your method now.

I hadn't looked at the abstract you linked to--and you're right, it's exactly the same approach I describe here, right down to the generalization to all interpolation methods that are linear functions of the $y_i.$
